# Help with this analysis problem, on definite integrals.

Tags: real-analysis, definite-integrals, continuity

Let $a,b>0$ and $f$ be the function defined by $f(x)=\int_a ^ b t ^ x dt$. Calculate $f(−1)$ and show that f is continuous at $x=−1$.

My doubt comes because I think being $a, b> 0$ then $t\not=0$ in $[a, b]$, and $t^x$ would be continuous for any value of x, right?

Comment: Proper integral from continuous on some rectangle function is continuous - did not fully understand what you doubt?

Comment: @zkutch My question is because then the problem would be very straightforward, and I wasn't sure if it should be like I'm thinking, so $t^x$ is continuous and the integral of a continuous function is continuous, and that's it?

Comment: After you fixed rectangle for $(t,x)$ on which $t^x$ is continuous, then that's it, nothing more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the first part, you get
$$
f(-1) = \int_a^b\frac1t\,dt = \big[\ln(t)\big]_a^b = \ln(b)-\ln(a) = \ln\left(\frac{b}{a}\right).
$$
In order to show that $f$ is continuous at $x=-1$, we must show that $|f(-1+\varepsilon)-f(-1)| \to 0$ as $\varepsilon \to 0$. We have
\begin{align}
|f(-1+\varepsilon)-f(-1)| &= \left| \int_a^b t^{-1+\varepsilon}dt - \int_a^bt^{-1}dt \right|\\
&= \left| \int_a^b (t^{-1+\varepsilon}-t^{-1})dt \right|\\
&\leq (t^{\varepsilon}-1)\int_a^b t^{-1}dt.
\end{align}
The function $g(t) := t^{-1}$ is continuous on $[a,b]$, since $a,b>0$. Moreover, $g$ is bounded on $[a,b]$, since this interval is compact. So $\int_a^bt^{-1}dt < \infty$, and hence
$$
\lim_{\varepsilon\to0}\;\;(t^{\varepsilon}-1)\int_a^b t^{-1}dt = 0,
$$
so in particular $|f(-1+\varepsilon)-f(-1)| \to 0$. Hope this helps!

Comment: I loved it, it is precisely what I was looking for, thank you very much

Comment: Glad I could help